# Symfony2 UserBundle

Tags: symfony

After several tries to install **`FSO UserBundle`** I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'symfony \ Component \
>   DependencyInjection \ Exception \ NonExistentServiceException'with
>   message 'The service "fos_user.form.user"has a dependency was
>   non-existent service "form.context". "in

any idea?

Comment: I currently have the same issue. I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: Have you run `bin/vendors install` in a while?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you clone the symfony2 repository after that fabien merged the form refractorisation ([See this commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/0069a70e42c74205a888aa7b5f1743700b24a51f)).

As far as i can see, the userbundle will soon get updated to include the changes with forms ([see here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/UserBundle/issues/112))